# NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/model/StreamedContent

Tags: jsf, primefaces, wildfly

Im using wildfly and primefaces 5.1, project was working fine, i restarted the app and i've suddenly got this error, any help please...

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/primefaces/model/StreamedContent
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
    at org.jboss.as.jsf.deployment.JSFManagedBeanProcessor.deploy(JSFManagedBeanProcessor.java:101)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.2.0.Final.jar:8.2.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ProjetMaven</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProjetMaven</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>org.omnifaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>omnifaces</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.18</version>
</dependency>

    <groupId>net.htmlparser.jericho</groupId>
    <artifactId>jericho-html</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
<artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
<version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
    <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ejb-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This error indicates PF library is not being properly deployed to your server.

Comment: how can i fix this problem, thanks, im using maven build

Comment: Do you want to share your pom?